# Pure HTML 5 tag support in JSF 2

Tags: html, jsf

I want to use plain HTML 5 in my JSF page as some UI functionality cannot be achieved by HTML support provided by JSF2.

---

In JSF 2.0, some attributes of HTML 5 form elements cannot be rendered correctly in the standard JSF input components.

For eg,`<input type="email"` cannot be rendered by `<h:inputText type="email"`.

In the below given [link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HTML5-JSF/html5jsf.html), they have used some pure HTML 5 tags like  `<canvas> <header> <footer> <small>` etc.

Now my questions are:

1. When I try to use the pure html input tag with type "text" in my JSF page, I cant able to retrieve the value from my Managed Bean and set it to this text box. why the value is not displayed?
2. Only some plain HTML 5 tags will be supported in xhtml page or all the plain HTML 5 tags will be supported

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HTML5 Support was [added in JSF2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1089). Since then you can add passthrough Attributes to JSF-Components:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough">
  <h:form>
    <h:inputText p:type="email" />
  </h:form>
</html>
```

Attributes which are not known will be ignored by JSF (2.0 and 2.2). If you need to render HTML5-Attributes with JSF2.0 you can use [Omnifaces HTML5 Renderkit](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit).

Pure HTML-Tags are just pure HTML-Tags. They are no JSF components. So they will be rendered to the view but JSF won't care about them and won't update your Model.

JSF2.2 came also with [Passthrough Elements](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2012/11/01/html5-friendly-markup-jsf-22). Now it's possible to turn a HTML-Tag to a JSF-Component:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <input jsf:id="foo" type="text" jsf:value="#{bean.bar}">
</html>
```

JSF knows that there is a [corresponding UIComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagDecorator.html) and will convert this HTML-Tag to a h:inputText. If there is no corresponding UIComponent JSF will create a special one which supports ajax.

See also: [JSF 2.2: HTML5 friendly markup](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5/)