# set <input type="radio" value in JSF backing bean

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I make use of JSF , now I need to change the style of the radio buton by using plain HTML5 tag  . How can I use the html tag to replace this

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="selectedAnswer" value="#{testBean.userAnswer}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="selectedAnswer" render="@none" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.question.answers}" var="selectedAnswer" itemLabel="#{selectedAnswer.answer}" itemValue="#{selectedAnswer.id}" />

</h:selectOneRadio>
```

with this:

```
<ui:repeat var="selectedAnswer" value="#{testBean.question.answers}">
    <label for="#{selectedAnswer.id}"> 
        <input type="radio" id="#{selectedAnswer.id}" name="a-radio" value="#{selectedAnswer.id}" >

        </input> 
        <span>#{selectedAnswer.answer}</span>
    </label> 
</ui:repeat>
```

How Can I set the value in the backing bean, in JSF you do this `<h:selectOneRadio value="#{testBean.userAnswer}"`. in HTML what do you do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600823/pure-html-5-tag-support-in-jsf-2

Comment: That does not help, in my question the input is of type 'radio' not 'text', it's not the same, text is obvious, but not radio.

Comment: You might want to replace `text` with `radio`...