# Difference between id attribute and jsf:id

Tags: html, jsf

I'm trying to understand how to add JSF capabilities to an HTML5 document (instead of doing the other way around), and now I see that if I add a `jsf:id` attribute to an element, the attribute is rendered in the browser as-is (`jsf:id`) and not as simply `id` (it doesn't happend with `jsf:value` in a `<input>` element, which is rendered as simply `value`). And now I've seen that some people add both attributes `id` and `jsf:id`. Now i am confused.

I understand that I need `id` if, for instance, I want to access that element via jQuery, but why do I need `jsf:id` then? couldn't I just add the `jsf` namespace to other attributein the same element so that the element is processed by the JSF engine, or is `jsf:id` useful for something else (in the managed bean maybe)?

Thanks

Comment: What  html tag/element did you add `jsf:id` to  where it did not work? Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600823/pure-html-5-tag-support-in-jsf-2

Comment: This is the tag in my `xhtml`: `<input type="email" placeholder="email" jsf:id="email" jsf:value="#{user.email}" />` and this is the rendered result: `<input type="email" placeholder="email" jsf:id="email" value="foo@bar.baz">`

Comment: You can edit your question and add relevant things like this in there

Comment: Sure you use the right namespace for the `jsf:` prefix??

Comment: I'm using this `xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"`