# Make use of HTML 5 download attribute in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm going to map external resources (files) to JSF form. I need to download file on button click. In normal html site I just use 
`<a href="http://asdas/resource/file.jpg" download="MyImage">Download image</a>`. Does JSF / Primefaces support `download` attribute?

Comment: What exactly stops you from just using the `<a>` element? Plain HTML works just fine in a JSF file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600823/pure-html-5-tag-support-in-jsf-2